# variable to return all results from a full text search?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, full-text-search

This is my first time using the full text search feature in MySQL.

I am using PDO statements and a select * statement.

```sql
SELECT *   
FROM `table` 
WHERE MATCH (var1) AGAINST (:field1 IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND MATCH (var2) AGAINST (:field2 IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

If var1 or var2 are undefined, what variable can I set them to so that all results from field1 or field2 are displayed?  Currently I get no results.

Before using Full Text search I would use

```
if (!isset($var1)) {
    $var1 = '%' . '' . '%';
}
```

with a LIKE statement that would return all results when a user has not specified any selection, etc.

I have tried using * but this doesn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: Change the conditions in case one of the vars (or both) are null - regex is expensive, don't make your DB work hard in vain.

Comment: This is not recommended to search for empty string using full text search and this will be a load to your mysql. Its always better to set the ft_min_word_len to a number such that no result is returned and by default its 4 so sending 0 word length will return nothing on full text search. If both var1 and var2 are empty and u still want to display all data then just use simple query and display all.

Comment: ok thanks, Ill try it this way instead